# Authorize.net payment method configuration not saving

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, authorize.net, braintree

I am trying to configure authorize.net payment settings in an magento 2 install. When I edit the payment method values, the default values are reset after I save (i.e. I enable Authorize.net, save and it is disabled).

I tested other payment methods such as braintree and paypal and they all worked fine as expected.

See example screenshots.

Before save - with updated settings input:
[image]

After save - returned to default or blank.
[image]

I have not been able to find anything online describing this behavior. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem which is similar to this.

In system configuration store view I have chosen the `Default config` and then choose `yes` on authorize.net enabled payment method.

Then click on save config, which works fine. That configuration was saved.

But now I would change the store view as `main webiste`, automatically chose `no` on authorize.net enabled payment method.

And also nearby use default value checkbox was changed to uncheckable.

I'm using magento version2.2.3

And I have tried the authorize.net payment method in one new magento 2.2.3 version package. It working fine.

I don't know exactly. If any other module conflict with this.

I hope your answer is helpful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have fixed this issue. Because in my code there is config save restriction on .htaccess file. 
@Todd, you can please check your .htaccess file for such type of restriction.